# How do I use a Vulkano compute shader to compute to a swapchain image?

Tags: rust, vulkan

I'm trying to calculate something with a compute shader and save the result in a swapchain image to display it in a window for later interactivity.

I get the following error message:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: AccessError { error: ImageNotInitialized { requested: PresentSrc }, command_name: "vkCmdBindDescriptorSets", command_param: "Image bound to descriptor 0 of set 0", command_offset: 1 }', libcore\result.rs:1009:5
>   note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
>   error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\vulkan_test.exe` (exit code: 101)

#### main.rs

```rust
extern crate vulkano;
extern crate vulkano_shaders;
extern crate vulkano_win;
extern crate winit;

use std::sync::Arc;
use vulkano::command_buffer::AutoCommandBufferBuilder;
use vulkano::descriptor::descriptor_set::PersistentDescriptorSet;
use vulkano::device::{Device, DeviceExtensions};
use vulkano::instance::{Instance, PhysicalDevice};
use vulkano::pipeline::ComputePipeline;
use vulkano::swapchain;
use vulkano::swapchain::{
    AcquireError, PresentMode, SurfaceTransform, Swapchain, SwapchainCreationError,
};
use vulkano::sync;
use vulkano::sync::{FlushError, GpuFuture};
use vulkano_win::VkSurfaceBuild;
use winit::{EventsLoop, WindowBuilder};

mod cs {
    vulkano_shaders::shader! {
    ty: "compute",
    // path: "shaders/compute.glsl"
        src: "
#version 450

layout(local_size_x = 8, local_size_y = 8, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(set = 0, binding = 0, rgba8) uniform writeonly image2D img;

void main() {
    imageStore(img, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(1,0,1,1));
}        
        "
    }
}

fn main() {
    let instance = {
        let extensions = vulkano_win::required_extensions();
        Instance::new(None, &extensions, None).expect("failed to create instance")
    };

    let physical = PhysicalDevice::enumerate(&instance)
        .next()
        .expect("no device available");

    println!("Name:    {}  (type: {:?})", physical.name(), physical.ty());
    println!("Version: {}", physical.api_version());

    let mut events_loop = EventsLoop::new();

    let surface = WindowBuilder::new()
        .with_title("Ray")
        .with_dimensions((1600.0, 900.0).into())
        .build_vk_surface(&events_loop, instance.clone())
        .expect("failed to create window");
    let window = surface.window();

    let queue_family = physical
        .queue_families()
        .find(|&q| q.supports_graphics() && surface.is_supported(q).unwrap_or(false))
        .expect("failed to create queue family");

    let (device, mut queues) = {
        let device_ext = DeviceExtensions {
            khr_swapchain: true,
            ..DeviceExtensions::none()
        };
        Device::new(
            physical,
            physical.supported_features(),
            &device_ext,
            [(queue_family, 0.5)].iter().cloned(),
        )
        .expect("failed to create device")
    };
    let queue = queues.next().expect("failed to create queue");

    let shader = cs::Shader::load(device.clone()).expect("failed to create shader module");

    let compute_pipeline = Arc::new(
        ComputePipeline::new(device.clone(), &shader.main_entry_point(), &())
            .expect("failed to create compute pipeline"),
    );

    let (mut swapchain, mut images) = {
        let caps = surface.capabilities(physical).unwrap();

        let usage = caps.supported_usage_flags;
        let alpha = caps.supported_composite_alpha.iter().next().unwrap();
        let format = caps.supported_formats[0].0;

        let initial_dimensions = if let Some(dimensions) = window.get_inner_size() {
            let dimensions: (u32, u32) = dimensions.to_physical(window.get_hidpi_factor()).into();
            [dimensions.0, dimensions.1]
        } else {
            return;
        };
        Swapchain::new(
            device.clone(),
            surface.clone(),
            caps.min_image_count,
            format,
            initial_dimensions,
            1,
            usage,
            &queue,
            SurfaceTransform::Identity,
            alpha,
            PresentMode::Fifo,
            true,
            None,
        )
        .expect("failed to create swapchain")
    };

    let mut recreate_swapchain = false;
    let mut previous_frame_end = Box::new(sync::now(device.clone())) as Box<GpuFuture>;

    loop {
        previous_frame_end.cleanup_finished();

        if recreate_swapchain {
            let dimensions = if let Some(dimensions) = window.get_inner_size() {
                let dimensions: (u32, u32) =
                    dimensions.to_physical(window.get_hidpi_factor()).into();
                [dimensions.0, dimensions.1]
            } else {
                return;
            };

            let (new_swapchain, new_images) = match swapchain.recreate_with_dimension(dimensions) {
                Ok(r) => r,
                Err(SwapchainCreationError::UnsupportedDimensions) => continue,
                Err(err) => panic!("{:?}", err),
            };

            swapchain = new_swapchain;
            images = new_images;
            recreate_swapchain = false;
        }

        let (image_index, acquire_future) =
            match swapchain::acquire_next_image(swapchain.clone(), None) {
                Ok(r) => r,
                Err(AcquireError::OutOfDate) => {
                    recreate_swapchain = true;
                    continue;
                }
                Err(err) => panic!("{:?}", err),
            };

        let command_buffer = {
            let set = Arc::new(
                PersistentDescriptorSet::start(compute_pipeline.clone(), 0)
                    .add_image(images[image_index].clone())
                    .unwrap()
                    .build()
                    .unwrap(),
            );

            AutoCommandBufferBuilder::new(device.clone(), queue.family())
                .unwrap()
                .dispatch([200, 100, 1], compute_pipeline.clone(), set.clone(), ())
                .unwrap()
                .build()
                .unwrap()
        };

        let future = previous_frame_end
            .join(acquire_future)
            .then_execute(queue.clone(), command_buffer)
            .unwrap()
            .then_swapchain_present(queue.clone(), swapchain.clone(), image_index)
            .then_signal_fence_and_flush();

        match future {
            Ok(future) => {
                previous_frame_end = Box::new(future) as Box<_>;
            }
            Err(FlushError::OutOfDate) => {
                recreate_swapchain = true;
                previous_frame_end = Box::new(sync::now(device.clone())) as Box<_>;
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("{:?}", e);
                previous_frame_end = Box::new(sync::now(device.clone())) as Box<_>;
            }
        }

        let mut done = false;
        events_loop.poll_events(|ev| match ev {
            winit::Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } => match event {
                winit::WindowEvent::CloseRequested => done = true,
                winit::WindowEvent::KeyboardInput {
                    input:
                        winit::KeyboardInput {
                            virtual_keycode: Some(virtual_code),
                            state: winit::ElementState::Released,
                            ..
                        },
                    ..
                } => match virtual_code {
                    winit::VirtualKeyCode::Escape => done = true,
                    _ => (),
                },
                winit::WindowEvent::Resized(_) => recreate_swapchain = true,
                _ => (),
            },
            _ => (),
        });
        if done {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Full error backtrace

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: AccessError { error: ImageNotInitialized { requested: PresentSrc }, command_name: "vkCmdBindDescriptorSets", command_param: "Image bound to descriptor 0 of set 0", command_offset: 1 }', libcore\result.rs:1009:5
stack backtrace:
   0: std::sys::windows::backtrace::set_frames
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\sys\windows\backtrace\mod.rs:104
   1: std::sys::windows::backtrace::set_frames
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\sys\windows\backtrace\mod.rs:104
   2: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\sys_common\backtrace.rs:71
   3: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\sys_common\backtrace.rs:71
   4: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\panicking.rs:211
   5: std::panicking::default_hook
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\panicking.rs:227
   6: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\panicking.rs:476
   7: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\panicking.rs:390
   8: std::panicking::rust_begin_panic
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\panicking.rs:325
   9: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libcore\panicking.rs:77
  10: core::result::unwrap_failed<vulkano::command_buffer::traits::CommandBufferExecError>
             at \libcore\macros.rs:26
  11: core::result::Result<vulkano::command_buffer::traits::CommandBufferExecFuture<vulkano::sync::future::join::JoinFuture<alloc::boxed::Box<GpuFuture>, vulkano::swapchain::swapchain::SwapchainAcquireFuture<winit::Window>>, vulkano::command_buffer::auto::AutoCommandBuffer<vulkano::command_buffer::pool::standard::StandardCommandPoolAlloc>>, vulkano::command_buffer::traits::CommandBufferExecError>::unwrap<vulkano::command_buffer::traits::CommandBufferExecFuture<vulkano::sync::future::join::JoinFuture<alloc::boxed::Box<GpuFuture>, vulkano::swapchain::swapchain::SwapchainAcquireFuture<winit::Window>>, vulkano::command_buffer::auto::AutoCommandBuffer<vulkano::command_buffer::pool::standard::StandardCommandPoolAlloc>>,vulkano::command_buffer::traits::CommandBufferExecError>
             at \libcore\result.rs:808
  12: vulkan_test::main
             at .\src\main.rs:178
  13: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}<()>
             at \libstd\rt.rs:74
  14: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\rt.rs:59
  15: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\rt.rs:59
  16: panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libpanic_unwind\lib.rs:102
  17: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\panicking.rs:289
  18: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\panicking.rs:289
  19: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/b6c32da9b0481e3e9d737153286b3ff8aa39a22c\src/libstd\panicking.rs:289
  20: std::rt::lang_start<()>
             at \libstd\rt.rs:74
  21: main
  22: invoke_main
             at d:\agent\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
  23: invoke_main
             at d:\agent\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
  24: BaseThreadInitThunk
  25: RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: Do You create a swapchain with appropriate image usage specified? Only color attachment usage is guaranteed to be supported. You set usage to include all available usages but You don't check whether appropriate usage (storage image?) is there.

Comment: I have printed the `caps.supported_usage_flags` and got the following message `ImageUsage { transfer_source: true, transfer_destination: true, sampled: true, storage: true, color_attachment: true, depth_stencil_attachment: false, transient_attachment: false, input_attachment: true }`. So a `storage` image is part of it.

Comment: Then this is not the cause of Your problem in this case. But to make sure Your code is correct, You should always check this. Your computer may support storage usage, but other computers may not not. And when You run Your application on another computer it may not work as You expect it to (even if You resolve Your current problem).

Answer (score 1):

Per the Vulkano doc:

> ImageNotInitialized
>   Trying to use an image without transitioning it from the "undefined" or "preinitialized" layouts first.

Assumably the Image is in `Undefined` layout, but it seems to require the `PresentSrc` per the trace.

Comment: Per the Vulkano doc of `ImageLayout`: _Transitionning between layouts can only be done through a GPU-side operation that is part of a command buffer._ It's not clear for me how to do this?

Comment: @JensMetzner Either as a part of a render pass setup (initialLayout, finalLayout and subpassLayout fields), or through an image memory barrier (part of vkCmdPipelineBarrier() command).

Comment: @Ekzuzy I added an `FrameBuffer` and also a render pass `.begin_render_pass(framebuffer.clone(),false,vec![[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0].into()],).unwrap().end_render_pass()` and now it works. It seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/issues/977)